# Add new TableView to another UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

My app setup is the following

[image]

With this setup, when I press the button in table 2 it pushes the view (table3) in the "nav 2" hierarchy.

What I need to do is to press the button on table 2 and push the view (table3) but in the hierarchy of the "nav 1". And if I press the "back" button in table 3, I want to go to the "Table 1", and NOT being able to return to the table2 view.

I need to do this programmatically. Im a beginner in iOS development, and I know I should modify use the method:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:..........];
```

But the problem is that in this way I am pushing it to the navigation controller of "self" meaning nav2. How do I push it to nav1?

**NOTE:** The layout I need is similar to the one found in "Messages" app when adding a new message thread.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to model the Messages app of navigation, you need to present a modal view controller with a navigation controller.

```
NewViewController *newVC = [[NewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *newNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newVC];
[newVC release];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:newNav animated:YES];
```

Comment: Okay, but my problem is that if i click a button that pushes a third view on the new view controller I've just created, the third view is anchored to the new navigation controller, and not to the original.

Comment: You can certainly nest more than one modal view, but you should really make sure they are not necessary. Modal Views are supposed to be temporary changes to your navigation model. In a pinch, you could add a notification to the middle view to dismiss if you need to drop from 3rd to first view. But I'd honestly make sure they are necessary before getting to modal view happy.

Answer (score 0):

In the message app, it looks like they are presented in a modal view. Then if you press the + button to get to the contacts it brings up another modal view wrapped in a NavigationController. If your using X-ode 4.2 and create a new ViewController in the storyboard there an option in the editor menu to embed that view in a NavigationController. then just present that view modally.